# Association of Python files in Windows not working

Tags: python, windows, file-association

On my system (Windows Vista Home Premium 64bit) Python files are associated with Python interpreter:

```
C:\Users\Piotr>assoc .py
.py=Python.File
C:\Users\Piotr>ftype Python.File
Python.File=c:\python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Nevertheless when I run any Python script from command line a window titled *Open With* pops up asking me to *Choose the program you want to use to open this file*.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> on a .py file in explorer and selecting "open with..." and then manually selecting the python interpreter.

Comment: I have a couple of Python installations and I wrote batch files to switch among them. Manual procedure you describe is out of question.

Comment: This breaks drag and drop, and argument passing

Comment: @Eric You can re-run the original `assoc` and `ftype` commands to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

no, Keltari's suggestion should work. there is another checkbox that asks whether to use the settings for all files of this type.

Also, make sure your PATH (system/user environment variable) includes the path to your python executable.

Answer (score -1):

Press right click on one of the codes you already have, and choose the IDE (or whatever else) you want to open the .py file with, and choose to make it the default app to open those files.
Hope it helped.