# Fixing Python file association

Tags: python

I'm learning python on x64 windows 7 machine. But after installing and uninstalling python 2.7 and 3.2 a few times too many (i just found out 3.x doesn't support some of the 3rd party libraries like PIL), i have lost .py file association(when i double click my python scripts, windows asks me to choose a program to open it with instead of making python interpret it). How can i fix the issue?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Fixing this is done the same way you'd fix it any other time you had it.

Comment: "you'd fix it any other time you had it"??

Comment: double-click again, lead Windows to `pythonw.exe`, and check the option that tells Windows to use it for all future `.py` files as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Association of Python files in Windows not working](http://superuser.com/questions/328146/association-of-python-files-in-windows-not-working)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

considering you've already set the path in environment variables:

open `command prompt`:

`cd` to the directory  which contains `lost.py` and then type:

`python lost.py` and hit enter.

or using IDLE:

start IDLE --> press CTRL+O --> open your file --> press F5

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: You got downvoted because you did not answer the question of "how do I fix my file associations" but instead answered "how do I run my python file".

Answer (score 0):

From an elevated command prompt:

```bash
C:\Windows\System32>assoc .py=PythonFile
.py=PythonFile

C:\Windows\System32>ftype PythonFile=py.exe "%1" %*
PythonFile=python.exe "%1" %*
```

Notice that the `""` are included in the `ftype` output.

---

Alternatively, use [FileTypesMan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html).